# SelectLayerByLocation - arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, select-by-location

I have 2 layers: "atikot" and "ways" that located in C:\Project\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb , and i try to use this code
based on "ArcGIS Help 10.2" to select features from "ways" layer:

```
 import arcpy
 arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Project\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb"
 arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('atikot', 'atikot_lyr') 
 arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('atikot_lyr', 'intersect', 'ways')
```

i run the script and nothing happened
anyone can help me ?

Comment: Where are you running your script? ArcMap, ArcCatalog, IDE?

Comment: with python 2.75

Comment: i run the code in ArcMap

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: If you want to see the selection in your map, 'atikot' should be the layer in the TOC of your mxd, not a feature class on your disk.

Comment: After you made the spatial selection, you may use the "Feature Class to Feature Class" function to save the selected features from feature layer ("atikot_lyr") to a new feature class.

Comment: i want to export the selected features to shape file into the workspace,how i do it?

Comment: You can use @VanniZhang approach to export to a shapefile. However you cant save a shapefile into a geodatabase which is set as your current workspace you would have to specify a different output path to save it as a shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i worked with this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
from arcpy import env


arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Project\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('atikot', 'atikot_lyr')  
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('atikot_lyr', 'INTERSECT', 'ways')
arcpy.Select_analysis("atikot_lyr", "output", '')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach to selecting features and then exporting the selection to a shapefile.

```
import arcpy

# Define Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Project\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb"
# Create Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('atikot', 'atikot_lyr')
# Select
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('atikot_lyr', 'intersect', 'ways')
# Copy Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('atikot_lyr', 'C:/foo/bar/atikot_select.shp', "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Comment: just a note the last four parameters in CopyFeatures_management are optional so you don't have to include them if you aren't going to specify values for them.